How to change the Python interpreter used by gdb
OS: cnetos7.6
I tried compile gdb --with-python，But I don't know why the error is reported，for example /gdb/ser-tcp.c:60:13: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef int socklen_t’，There are many more similar errors.
I also tried to export PYTHONHOME=/usr/bin/python3 , but it failed too.
I would like to change the python interpreter gdb uses ,to use deadlock.py.
I would like to use deadlock.py to gdb c++ program, instead of gdb python program.
